# «какой» как указательное местоимение

Tags: местоимения

Как известно, слова вроде «какой», «что», «сколько» и т.д. относятся к разряду вопросительных/относительных местоимений. Относительные местоимения соединяют части сложного предложения, вопросительные же указывают на вопрос, логично. Но что делать в таких случаях, как:
*«Какой прекрасный день!»*
*«Какая ты умная» и тд.*

Не являются ли слова «какой» и «какая» в данном случае указательными местоимениями?

Answer (score 2):

Из толкового словаря:

**КАКОЙ,**  местоим. прил. 3. (в восклиц. предл.). Употр. для выражения **эмоциональной оценки** говорящим какого-л. явления, действия, субъекта (удивление, негодование, восхищение и т.п.). Какой же ты трус!

Здесь местоименное прилагательное ***какой*** переходит из класса местоимений **в класс частиц** с эмоционально-экспрессивным значением.

А классификация по семантическому признаку (**9 разрядов**) относится именно  к местоимениям, поэтому в данном случае неприменима.

И по этой классификации **указательными** являются местоимения ***этот, тот, такой, столько.***